# "Access Denied" on writing on Mailslot in Windows Service program

Tags: delphi, windows-services, mailslot

I use Mailslots (in Delphi 7) for inter-programs dialog and all is OK.

But when I use one of my program (in Windows XP) as Windows service I have a message  "Mailslot Access Denied", when another (classical admin user's)  program try to write to the mailslot.
I Understand that it is surely a rights problem since service have SYSTEM rights but...what is the solution ?

Comment: Who is creating the mailslot - the service or the app?  What security attributes are being specified in the `lpSecurityAttributes` parameter of `CreateMailslot()`? It makes a big difference when dealing with services. If the service is creating the mailslot, then you will most likely need to assign a non-NULL `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` object that allows anonymous access to the mailslot.

Comment: @RemyLebeau-TeamB OK, the service create the MailSlot, I see now lpSecurityAttributes. It is nil in my applications. I look how to assign it to a non-Null object...

Comment: see my answer. I have provided a code snippet now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling `CreateMailslot()`, specify a `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR` that allows all access to the mailslot, eg:

```
var
  ...
  sd: SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;
  sa: SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES; 
begin
  ...
  InitializeSecurityDescriptor(@sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
  SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(@sd, True, nil, False);

  sa.lpSecurityDescriptor := @sd; 
  sa.bInheritHandle := Frue; 

  ... := CreateMailslot(..., @sa);
  ...
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

I use C++ Embarcardero 2010, and I have to do some modifications to the solution of [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau) because the CreateMailSlot function receive a pointer of type SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES *, and not a pointer of type SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR *.

My solution in C++ is:

```
SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
InitializeSecurityDescriptor(&sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(&sd, true, NULL, false);

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor=&sd;
sa.bInheritHandle=true;
this->pHandleMailSlot = CreateMailslot("your mail slot path", 0, -1, &sa);
```

---

Note: In my case  I've three applications:

1. A service with the MailSlot (Embarcadero C++ 2010)
2. A service with a client mailslot (.NET v4)
3. A WPF with a client mailslot (.NET v4)

Comment: Unless you actually need spawned processes to inherit the handle, I would set `sa.bInheritHandle` to false instead.